# Testing private controller methods when using 'Controller As' syntax

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I would be interested to hear how other people are doing this.

I'm following John Papa's guidelines, and using a `vm` variable and `Controller As` syntax where `vm` is set to `this` in the controller. To expose the 'private' methods in the controller and allow them to be tested they would have to be attached to `this`, which means that they would also pollute the scope. Is the only solution to do a shedload of refactoring and break the private methods out into services that can then be tested?

Comment: You should test your controller as if it were a 'black box'. The test should use the controller the way your directives/components does. No need to expose private members.

Comment: So, for example I have a private method that contains an event handler which calls a private method when the event is triggered - testing in this way would mean that none of this would be be tested - is this acceptable?

Comment: The private method that is called when the event is triggered actually updates a $scope (vm) variable - so I guess then the proper way to test all this would be by triggering the event and testing this exposed value? Is that the proper way of doing things?

Comment: Yes, broadcast the event and test if the controller did what it was supposed to do! If the changes affects the view it migh be a good idea to compile and test the whole component/directive rather than the isolated controller. That way you can actually test if the DOM updates the way it should.

Comment: Cool -  thanks very much for the help :)